# Editing/adding IPTC metadata in Android app

Tags: java, android, image-processing, exif, iptc

I have looked at many of the other similar questions but none of them seem to have a precise answer.

I'm working on an Android app that works with a lot of images. I am looking to add information to images by editing the value of their IPTC keyword tag (or other appropriate tags). I am using [Metadata Extractor](http://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/) for reading metadata but this library doesn't support writing metadata.

I have looked at [Apache Sanselan](http://commons.apache.org/imaging/) which doesn't seem to be appropriate because it has heavy dependency on `java.awt` (which is not available in Android). I'm aware of [Imagero](http://reader.imagero.com/) but I have not used it yet in the hope of finding a better open source library.

Has anyone come across such a library? I prefer it to be open source but even commercial suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/dragon66/pixymeta-android) is an Android library I made to extract and insert metadata from/into images.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/k3b/pixymeta-android/ is a fork of https://github.com/dragon66/pixymeta-android/ that implemented

- single source for android and jave2se/awt

However there is still a lot of work to implement a simple to use api

Answer (score -1):

Use http://sourceforge.net/projects/iim4j/ Won't work out of box, but can be adapted. I did it to add Copyright notice and Contact fields. Didn't tried other fields, as I didn't needed them. So that would be your bet.

Sorry, can't share the code.

Comment: IIM4J was moved to https://github.com/vnesek/nmote-iim4j ... It would be great if you could contribute changes for copyright notice and contact field.