# Embed IPTC metadata in images on android

Tags: android, iptc

In an android app, I want to write IPTC metadata in images. Does android provide a built-in support for this? If not, are there any open source libraries for android applications?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900445/

Answer (score 0):

Well, Android is programmed in Java, right? So this is IMHO a duplicate of at least [Java library for reading and writing IPTC metadata to JPEG and TIFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851665) and [Editing/adding IPTC metadata in Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900445/)

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+iptc

Comment: since java-j2se/awt-bitmapmaps are completly different from android-bitmaps most java-non-android-libs will not work for android.